# Does the built-in potential inside a diode change by making bias?

Tags: electric-fields, potential, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

under thermal equilibrium the pn junction have a built-in field let say it's $E_{1}$ , if we make a reverse bias the external battery provide a permanent field $E_{2}$ , so the total field inside the junction is $E_{tot}=E_{1}+E_{2}$ , but the external field of the battery will widen the depletion region making more charges inside it then the built-in field will change form being $E_{1}$ TO $E_{3}$ and the field of the battery is permanently exist , so that makes the total field inside the junction is equal to $E_{3}+E_{2}$ ?

Comment: You can't keep adding in the field from the battery over and over again.

Comment: @JonCuster  but the battery field is independent of the field inside the depletion region

Comment: the battery will widen the depletion region "making more charges inside it " how do you think that happens?

Comment: @trula, more charges will be inside the depletion region, because it's now has been wider

Comment: More charges not more charge density, so E stays the same.

Comment: @trula, I will summarize  what I've concluded from your comment to make sure that I understand the reason you provided correctly,,                                                 in first before we apply reverse potential the built-in field inside the diode is $E_{1}$ after we apply reverse field of $E_{2}$ the total field inside the diode is equal to $E_{1}+E_{2}$ , and the reverse field $E_{2}$ will widen the depletion region and add more charges to it but it won't change the original built-in field $E_{1}$ because it won't change the original charge density , is that correct?

Comment: Yes thats as far as I know.